# Connect NHibernate to different databases with same schema

Tags: nhibernate, session, sessionfactory

We are in the process of splitting our db into several smaller ones. The schemas will be exactly the same and we will control which db the system connects to when the client logs in. I receive an error if I do not set a connection string in my nhibernate configuration. I do not want to create a factory for each db.  Is it possible to have a session factory provide a Session that I can set the connection string before using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not used it but there is a method ChangedDatabase on the Session.Connection. Maybe that would work?

Comment: does factory.OpenSession create a new session each time or is it cached?

Comment: each time, and it is in-expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use NHibernate.Shards, in the NHcontrib repository